# Testing JAX RS service with Arquillian and Tomee embedded

Tags: jax-rs, java-ee-7, jboss-arquillian, tomee-7

I'm starting a new proyect with Tomee 7.0.0-M1 and I would like to test a JAX-RS service with Arquillian but I'm getting the following error when I run the test from Intellilj:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/loader/VirtualWebappLoader
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatLoader.initialize(TomcatLoader.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomee.embedded.Container.start(Container.java:318)
    at org.apache.openejb.arquillian.embedded.EmbeddedTomEEContainer.start(EmbeddedTomEEContainer.java:113)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:199)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:163)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:157)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:255)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:77)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:70)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forEachSuiteContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:221)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startSuiteContainers(ContainerLifecycleController.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeSuite(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:68)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:104)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 67 more
```

The curious thing is if I run the test from the console with maven then I get a different exception:

```
com.tr2.rest.bookings.BookingServiceTest  Time elapsed: 1.35 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/naming/resources/FileDirContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatLoader.initialize(TomcatLoader.java:222)
        at org.apache.tomee.embedded.Container.start(Container.java:318)
        at org.apache.openejb.arquillian.embedded.EmbeddedTomEEContainer.start(EmbeddedTomEEContainer.java:113)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:199)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:163)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:157)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:255)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:156)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My sources files are the following:

Test

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class BookingServiceTest {

    @Deployment(testable = true)
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
                .addClasses(
                        BookingService.class, 
                        GetBookingRS.class, 
                        GetBookingRQ.class);
    }
    @ArquillianResource
    private URL base;

    private static WebTarget target;

    @Before
    public void setUpClass() throws MalformedURLException {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        target = client.target(URI.create(new URL(base, "resources/booking/getBookings").toExternalForm()));
    }

    @Test
    public void testResponse() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Future<Response> r1 = target.request().async().get();
        Response response = r1.get();
    }

}
```

arquillian.xml

```
<container qualifier="tomee" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="httpPort">-1</property>
        <property name="stopPort">-1</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

pom dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-tomee-embedded</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomee-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>               
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.29</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>            
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-tomee</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0-M1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomee-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0-M1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
    <artifactId>openejb-cxf</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0-M1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.12</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
    <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any idea?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed the correct version of embedded tomee adapter:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-tomee-embedded</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0-M1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```